# How Should i use a jTable to represent a list of objects?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am writing a hockey pool manager program, and I am having trouble getting a jTable to represent my list of players. What i have are three classes, Team, Roster, and Player. Team has two Roster members, a Bench roster and a Lineup Roster. each roster contains an ArrayList of Players. Players can be added dynamically. I want to have two jTables, one to list players in the Bench Roster, and one for the Lineup Roster. I have made this table model, but i feel i am way off track:

```
public class PlayerTable extends AbstractTableModel {

    private String[] columnNames = {"Name", "Team", "Position", "Injured?", "Salary",     "PowerRanking"};
    private Roster playerList;

    public PlayerTable(Roster players){
    playerList = players;
    }
        public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
            return playerList.getNumPlayers();
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }
    public boolean addPlayer(String name, String team, int teamNumber) throws Exception{
        return playerList.addPlayer(name, team, teamNumber);

    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        Object returnValue = "----";
        switch (col) {
            case 0:
                returnValue = playerList.getPlayer(row).getName();
                break;
            case 1:
                returnValue = playerList.getPlayer(row).getTeam();
                break;
            case 2:
                returnValue = playerList.getPlayer(row).getPosition();
                break;
            case 3:
                returnValue = playerList.getPlayer(row).isInjured();
                break;
            case 4:
                returnValue = playerList.getPlayer(row).getSalary();
                break;
            case 5:
                returnValue = playerList.getPlayer(row).getPawerRanking();
                break;

        }
        return returnValue;

    }

    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }
}
```

And I am initializing my jTables with:

```
jTableBench.setModel(new PlayerTable(userTeam.getBench())
```

I get an empty Table, but it has the correct column names. now when I go and add a player to the Bench using

```
userTeam.addPlayerToBench(name, team...)
```

The table does not change. Am I on the right track here? is this the best way to use a table to represent an set of objects like this? How can i get the table to reflect the changes i have made to the Bench Roster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Bean Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/27/bean-table-model/) allows you to display custom Objects easily.

Answer (score 1):

Your table model needs to fire events to inform its view that the model has changed. In your case, you should use `fireTableRowsInserted(getRowCount() - 1, getRowCount() - 1)`. Look at the javadoc of `AbstractTableModel` to discover which events may be fired.

You should thus use the model to add a player. The model will add a player to the playerList it holds, and would also fire the appropriate event.

Comment: Do i need to do the Add player operation in the table model? I already have the logic to do it in the team class, and i was hoping that updating it there would update the roster in the table model.

Comment: correct advice would be ro adds some methods about TableMode#fireTableXxx to the AbstractTableModel code block ...